# KeyDown : detect either control key alone or control key used as a modifier

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The user will type in a datagridview the shortcuts he would like to assign to a couple of operations. I tried to use KeyDown event when the cell is in edit mode.

However I want my control to be able to detect in the same event handler the Control key typed alone, or the Control key used as a modifier (same with Shift and Alt).
This causes a problem since KeyDown fires up when Control is down before the other key I am combining it with is also down. Obviously the event handler doesn't know if the user intends on pressing another key after the Control key.

Right now I solved this issue by using KeyUp, but this caused other headaches when for example the user types in CTRL+P, releases P, which fires the correct event, but then the user releases Ctrl which fires a new KeyUp event which I had to find a way to ignore.

There must be a cleaner way to handle this?

Comment: so when doing `CTRL + P` your `keydown` fires 2 times, the first time with `ControlKey, Control` and the second time with `P, Control` correct ? But this will only be a problem if you define a shortcut with only `CTRL` and it seems logical to not allow that. `CTRL` is only to be used in combination, and the reason for that is exact the problem you describe. So, why do you want to allow a shortcut with only `CTRL`?

Comment: Yes you understood correctly, this is the heart of the problem. But I would like to have the most general possible shortcuts, and that includes `ControlKey` alone. Later I can decide I'm not allowing any particular keys

Comment: Using ControlKey alone as a shortcut, will only work of no combinations with ControlKey are defined. Its one or the other. Using ControlKey alone is mostly done in games, but you will see that in that case there is no combination possible. Or before the combination works, the ControlKey alone also worked for a little while until the combination was hit

Comment: Given that no other Windows developers anywhere ever use Ctrl alone, why would you think that it would be a good idea for you to do so? Just don't do it and the problem goes away. Just be sensible and you'll encounter fewer issues.